# How to Store value in Stack Pointer Register to Memory (8085)?

Tags: assembly, 8085

say I have a 16-bit address 1964h in SP register, how to copy this address to a consecutive 8-bit memory in 8085 ?

PS: I'm using SP for general purpose operations (eg. to store operands).

Comment: LXI SP, now you have it in HL and can do whatever you want with it.  Like SHLD to store it to memory.  You can't reasonably use SP for operands, an interrupt will kill you.  DI is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did it this way :

```
    lxi h,0h        ; initialize hl to zero
    dad sp          ; add sp to hl
    shld [dest]     ; store to memory
```

Comment: Seems like a reasonable way to do it - ISTR I had a macro to take care of such things...30+ years ago...

Answer (score 0):

I once had to write this for a boot prom (boot monitor) for a HD-mikko - a variant of Mikromikko 1.

```
; !----------------------------------------------------
; ! sptohl      0090
; !
; ! moves sp to hl (the value of sp before the call)
; !
; ! on return :
; !   hl = sp
; !   other registers are saved
; !
sptohl :
        push    psw
        lxi     h,00000h
        ana     a
        dad     sp
        inx     h
        inx     h
        inx     h
        inx     h
        pop     psw
        ret
```